# Recalling and conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions

At the end of a phone conversation about specific topic I have feeling that I didn't say everything. What should I say?
"If I recall something, I'll send it in e-mail"
or
"If I recalled something, I would write it in e-mail"
or maybe there is a better sentence?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: `If I remember anything else, I'll email you.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not

> If I recalled something, I would write it in e-mail.

because *recalled* is past tense. You haven't recalled it yet.

This is OK

> If I recall something, I'll send it in *an* e-mail.

I would say

> If I think of anything else, I'll send *you* an e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add a bit to user3169's answer.  I believe I understand your reason for asking this question: since sending the email is conditional upon your recalling something, you would like to use a specifically conditional tense, and you're having trouble finding one for future conditional situations.

We have two sorts of future conditional:

> If I go to the opera tonight, I will take a taxi.
>   If I were going to the opera tonight, I would take a taxi.

In the first sentence, I might be going and I might not.  But if I do, I will take a taxi.  In the second sentence, I'm not going; that decision has already been made.  But if I were, I would take a taxi.

The second sentence is often used as a polite way of giving advice.  In this case, perhaps someone is going to the opera, and you are suggesting that he take a taxi by saying that that is what you would do if you were in his place.  It makes the suggestion while avoiding telling the person what to do.  "You should take a taxi" is a more direct way of making the suggestion.